# Drawing - optimization

Tags: android, optimization, drawing

I need to draw something like a matrix of pixels. I created a lot of cells (500x500) and I fill them (= cellchecked). But I have problem with lag when I have more than 300 cells which are filled. This problem is inside onDraw method. Every time it have to checked cells anew. How can I optimize this fragment of code?

**onTouchEvent:**

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                column = (short) (event.getX() / cellWidth);
                row = (short) (event.getY() / cellHeight);

               plot(column, row);
               cellChecked[column][row] = true;

                pX = (short) (event.getX() / cellWidth);
                pY = (short) (event.getY() / cellHeight);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                column = (short) (event.getX() / cellWidth);
                row = (short) (event.getY() / cellHeight);

               cellChecked[column][row] = true;
                pX = (short) (event.getX() / cellWidth);
                pY = (short) (event.getY() / cellHeight);

                counterxy++;
                mInterface.onActionFinished(pX, pY, counterxy);        // Wyslanie wspolrzednych do MainActivity
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                invalidate();

                return true;


        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
}
```

**onDraw:**

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        if (numColumns == 0 || numRows == 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
            {
                if (cellChecked[i][j])
                {
                    canvas.drawRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, (i + 1) * cellWidth, (j + 1) * cellHeight, blackPaint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a 500x500 bitmap and (re)set pixels there when cells are (un)checked?

Declare fields in your class for the bitmap, paint and target rectangle:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect dst = new Rect();
```

Set a pixel using

```
setPixel(pX, pY, Color.BLACK);  // Use Color.WHITE to reset
```

In the constructor, disable anti-aliasing on the paint object to make sure the bitmap doesn't get blurred. Also clear the bitmap to the desired color:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(false);
paint.setFilterBitmap(false);
bmp.clear(Color.WHITE);
```

Draw the bitmap in onDraw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    dst.right = 500 * cellWidth;
    dst.bottom = 500 * cellHeight;

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dst, paint);
}
```